# how to set a variable as a list of values?

Tags: sql, variables, set, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to define a variable in Snowflake, which contains a list of values, so I can reuse this variable in different SQLs.

Here is the use case

`set account_list = 'ID1, ID2, ID3';`

I want to select these 3 accounts from the account table and various other tables

this query returns 3 records correctly

`select * from ACCOUNT where ACCOUNT_ID in (ID1, ID2, ID3);`

Neither queries below returns any matching records.

`select * from ACCOUNT where ACCOUNT_ID in ($account_list);`

`select * from ACCOUNT where ACCOUNT_ID in (select $account_list);`

Does anyone try to do the same before, and if you find a way to get it to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flatten function to convert the variable list into single column table and can use the variable values within the query.

Example: First, store the variable values as a string representation of a JSON array

set variable1 = '[value1,value2]';

Next, use the flatten table function to transform the variable list into a single column table. The keyword "value" is the name of the column returned by the flatten function. You can then use a subquery to return the values from the new table to a "where in ()" statement.

select * from 
where  in (select value from table(flatten ( input => parse_json($variable1))));